# Django post_save signal seemingly triggered only on 2nd save or after

Tags: django, django-signals

So I'm using a signal-triggered function on `post_save` to create instances of another model when the the first is saved:

The model triggering the signal:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # ...
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size)
```

And the function:

```
def create_skus(instance, **kwargs):
    for color in instance.colors.select_related():
        for size in instance.colors.select_related():
            SKU.objects.get_or_create(product=instance, color=color, size=size)
```

My issue is that `create_skus` should be called on post_save every time, but only seems to work on the 2nd save or after, resulting in users have to save a Product twice. What is the origin of this?

**EDIT**: I think this has something to do with how these M2M relations are added (i.e. `instance.colors.add(<Color object>)` but I'm not sure, and if you know of a workaround, I'd love you forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signal is sent when the Product instance is saved, not when the Color and Size instances are saved. Therefore, on the first try, your post_save() function's Product instance will not (yet) have the Color and Size instances, as they are not saved through the Product model's save() method.

Check out these two links:

- [A possible solution posted by a fellow SO'er](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221878/why-does-django-post-save-signal-give-me-pre-save-data/1251607#1251607)
- You could also work with the [m2m_changed signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).