# Django signal after whole model has been saved

Tags: python, django, signals

I have a Django model with 2 `ManyToMany` fields. I want to process the data from the model each time it has been saved.

The `post_save` signal is sent before it saves the `ManyToMany` relations, so I can't use that one. Then you have the `m2m_changed` signal, but since I have 2 `ManyToMany` fields I cannot be sure on which `ManyToMany` field I should put the signal.

Isn't there a signal that is triggered after all the `ManyToMany` fields have been saved?

Comment: Try this, found via a google: http://techblog.ironfroggy.com/2011/02/django-how-to-hook-in-after-multiple.html - might give you some pointers

Comment: Thanks, however the solution on the link you posted only works if you only use the Django admin. I need support when the model has been saved outside of the Django admin too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221878/why-does-django-post-save-signal-give-me-pre-save-data

Comment: @catherine the ticket they're talking about in the other SO question is what resulted in the m2m_changed signal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like the only option is to process the data after every `m2m_change`, since there doesn't appear to be an event or signal that maps to "all related data on this model has finished saving."

If this is high cost, you could handle the processing asynchronously. When I encountered a similar situation, I added a boolean field to the model to handle state as it related to processing (e.g., `MyModel.needs_processing`) and a separate asynchronous task queue (Celery, in my case) would sweep through every minute and handle the processing/state resetting.

In your case, if `m2m_changed` and `needs_processing` is `False`, you could set `needs_processing` to `True` and save the model, marking it for processing by your task queue. Then, even when the second `m2m_changed` fired for the other m2m field, it wouldn't incur duplicate processing costs.